# Finding an index in a list of generic objects with multiple conditions

Tags: c#

If I have a class that looks like this:

```
class test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OtherID { get; set; }
}
```

And makes a list of those objects:

```
private List<test> test = new List<test>();
```

If I wanna try to find an index in this I would write:

```
int index = test.FindIndex(item => item.ID == someIDvar);
```

But now I wonder if I can use this to make more than one condition without writing another function for it? Like if I want to check if ID matches with a var AND OtherID matches with another?

Comment: The same way you would do it in an `if`-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason why you can't make your predicate more complicated:

```
int index = test.FindIndex(item => item.ID == someIDvar
                                && item.OtherID == someOtherIDvar);
```

Comment: thx alot! Gonna accept this. What do you mean with no reason why I cant make my predicate?

Comment: @user3427831 apologies if this caused confusion. In general, a method (even an anonymous one), which takes some parameters and returning a bool is called a predicate. In your code that was the following: `item => item.ID == someIDvar`; it takes a `test` object and returns a bool - no reason this can't be as complex as you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
int index = test.FindIndex(item => item.ID == someIDvar && 
                                   item.OtherID == another);
```

In the above snippet we use the `&&` operator. Using the above snippet you will get the index of the first element in the list called test, that has a specific ID and a specific OtherID.

Another approach would be this one:

```
// Get the first element that fulfills your criteria.
test element = test.Where((item => item.ID == someIDvar && 
                           item.OtherID == another)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

// Initialize the index.
int index = -1

// If the element isn't null get it's index.
if(element!=null)
    index = test.IndexOf(element)
```

For further documentation, please take a look here [List.FindIndex Method (Predicate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: You are aware that this will not compile? Your `Select` method returns `IEnumerable<int>` not `int`.

Comment: @user3427831 exactly; as you can see the learning curve is not steep :)

Comment: @user3427831 yeap, this is linq

Answer (score 2):

Literally with `&&` (and) operator:

```
int index = test.FindIndex(item => item.ID == someIDvar
                                   && item.OtherID == otherIDvar);
```